# Есть ли обоснование запятой в данном примере?

Tags: пунктуация, однородные-члены

- Он предоставил Хрисанфу во владение все имущество как единственному наследнику, и в скором времени умер.

Comment: Встречались не раз такие простые предложения с однородными сказуемыми, соединенными союзом "и". Притом перед "и" почему-то ставилась запятая. Ее-то и хочется поставить, но какие основания? Может, распространенность одного из сказуемых или большая удаленность второго сказуемого от подлежащего?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Без оборота "как единственному наследнику" предложение будет таким:
*Он предоставил Хрисанфу во владение все имущество и в скором времени умер.*
Понятно, что в этом случае запятая не требуется.

Обычно такой оборот (поясняющий возникшие вопросы *почему? по какой причине?*) обособляется:

*Он вчера скончался и оставил вам (гром все усиливался, крепчал и вдруг обрушился самым оглушительным образом), как единственному наследнику, два дома и около трёхсот тысяч процентными бумагами!!!*
А. Аверченко. Повести и рассказы

*Два отв...ерстия вырыты в этих пещерах: клад зарыт в самом даль...нем углу второго отверстия; каковой клад завещаю ему и отдаю в по...лную собственность, как единственному моему наследнику.*
А Дюма. Граф Монте-Кристо. Т.1

В вашем предложении я бы поставила запятые.
**Он предоставил Хрисанфу во владение все имущество, как единственному наследнику, и в скором времени умер.**

Answer (score 1):

Он предоставил Хрисанфу во владение все имущество, **как единственному наследнику**, и в скором времени умер.

Оборот со значением причины обособляется.